# Warning: ClassLoader referenced unknown path in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I'm new to Android and Android Studio. I created a HelloWorld project in Android Studio. When I'm running the app on my device I get following warnings.. How can I fix these warnings?

```
6-15 11:21:22.287 962-962/com.rajiv.helloworld W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rajiv.helloworld-1/lib/arm
06-15 11:21:23.136 962-962/com.rajiv.helloworld W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.rajiv.helloworld-1/lib/arm
06-15 11:21:23.424 962-962/com.rajiv.helloworld W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

Comment: If you aren't running the app on an ARM chipset device, I'd say you can ignore the first 2

Answer (score 3):

It's a issue with **instant-Run** and for warning Before Android 4.1 as doc says:

> Instant Run is supported only when you deploy the debug build variant,
>   use Android Plugin for Gradle version 2.0.0 or higher, and set
>   minSdkVersion to 15 or higher in your app's module-level build.gradle
>   file. For the best performance, set minSdkVersion to 21 or higher.

you can see full [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run) here.

Recommended to disable **Instant-run** or set `min-sdk` to 15 or higher.

Comment: What about the ClassLoader referenced unknown path warning. How can I fix this?

Comment: @rajiv As I remember both issue gone when I set min sdk 15.

Comment: minSdkVersion is already set to 15, so this solution do not work

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the app ,So it forces the closure of the Instant Run. it worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing the same problem but i got solution here for you

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context,Route.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

i hope it will work for you