# Android studio support android version 6

Tags: android

I've made an application that was tested on three mobile phones. Two of them have android version 7 and application works on them without any errors. The third one has android version 6.01 and when I start application, it goes blank and on logcat there are 2 warnings:

```
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/com.ja.prog-1/lib/arm
```

Second one:

```
Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter
(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

Comment: Apparently you're using an external lib which use some non-Java code (like C) and is pre-compiled. This lib doesn't provide a compiled version of this code for the CPU of your 3rd phone. That's why it doesn't work.
What is this library btw?
So for me it's not related to the Android version but the phone hardware.

Comment: I use opengl to create image, but I don't use any C code or anything like that, all classes are in Java.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654701/1827254) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37827307/1827254) solutions?