# ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.myApp-1App-1/lib/arm64

Tags: android, android-studio, jacoco

I am new to Android.

I have created Reminder/Alarm Android Application.

I have tried to disable Instant Run in Android studio but that don't work.

I am facing this issue when my App is close on device only.
I don't face this issue when my App is running on device.

I read all below link but don't get any solution for my problem.
[ClassLoader reference unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827199/warning-classloader-referenced-unknown-path-in-android-studio-2-1-2)

I am facing below stacktrace:

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.myApp-1/lib/arm64
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jacoco.exec: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
W/System.err:     at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.output.FileOutput.openFile(FileOutput.java:67)
W/System.err:     at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.output.FileOutput.startup(FileOutput.java:49)
W/System.err:     at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.Agent.startup(Agent.java:122)
W/System.err:     at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.Agent.getInstance(Agent.java:50)
W/System.err:     at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.Offline.<clinit>(Offline.java:31)
W/System.err:     at com.myApp.MyApplication.$jacocoInit(MyApplication.kt)
W/System.err:     at com.myApp.MyApplication.<clinit>(MyApplication.kt)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:997)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:575)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4699)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
W/System.err:   ... 21 more
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
I/MultiDex: Installing application
I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
I/ReminderReceiver: Received intent: Intent { act=com.myApp.ACTION_SHOW_REMINDER dat=content://com.myApp/habit/1 flg=0x14 cmp=com.myApp/.receivers.ReminderReceiver (has extras) }
```

Pls suggest me to resolve above problem

Comment: Perhaps the error is not related to the ```ClassLoader``` but instead is related to the thrown exception. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15711268/2949966. Also posting the code that it is related to the question could help.

Comment: I think I got it, are you trying to locate ```jacoco.exec``` within root (```/```). You're most definitely not going to find it there...